# Extracting file icon and display in html

Tags: node.js, windows, electron

Evening Everyone,

I have started doing some research for an application i want to write using the electron framework. I have figured out how to display what i want to the user with the exception of the icons. There is a part of the application where the user can type a path and it will list the files in that path, i would like to pull the icon from the files so its displayed just like it would be in the windows file explorer. This is where i have been running into a roadblock and I'm looking for some guidance.

Is there a method in nodejs that would allow me to provide a file path and in return get a image back i can pass to HTML? Im new to nodejs so i figured i would ask and see if anyone knew of an easy way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [**icon-extractor**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icon-extractor)
you can use it like this to extract any app icon from the system , but it must be an**".exe"** file.

`var iconExtractor = require('icon-extractor');
 var fs= require('fs');`

```
iconExtractor.emitter.on('icon', function(data){
console.log('Here is my context: ' + data.Context);
console.log('Here is the path it was for: ' + data.Path);
var icon = data.Base64ImageData;

fs.writeFile('img.png', icon, 'base64', (err) => {
 console.log(err);

});
});

iconExtractor.getIcon('ANY_TEXT','PAHT_TO_APP.exe');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using electron, you might run into a lot of issues. For me no other package worked than this one:

[Windows Powershell Icon Extractor](https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/windows-system-icon/v/0.0.3)