# how to extract an icon from an exe file

Tags: javascript, file, electron, icons, exe

When I open a dialog window using Electron, select a file, I need to get the icon of this file

```
ipcMain.on('open-file-dialog',  () => {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({
      properties: ['openFile'],
      filters: [{ name: 'All Files', extensions: ['exe','url'] }]
    }).then(result => {
      if (!result.canceled && result.filePaths.length > 0) {
        const filePath = result.filePaths[0];
        fs.readFile(filePath, async(err) => {
          if (!err) {
            /*get icon*/
          } else {
            console.error(err);
          }
        });
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  });
```

Comment: If you can import, maybe take a look to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090459/extracting-file-icon-and-display-in-html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IconExtractor` to do this.

```
ipcMain.on('open-file-dialog',  () => {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({
      properties: ['openFile'],
      filters: [{ name: 'All Files', extensions: ['exe','url'] }]
    }).then(result => {
      if (!result.canceled && result.filePaths.length > 0) {
        const filePath = result.filePaths[0];
        iconExtractor.getIcon('Context (what the icon is for, used in emitter)',filePath);
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  });

iconExtractor.emitter.on('icon', data=()=>{
  console.log('Provided Context: ' + data.Context);
  console.log('Path: ' + data.Path);
  console.log('IMG: ' + data.Base64ImageData);
});
```